# If user picks a string on a ComboBox how do you get it to display?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-driven

I am trying to get the user's input for picking a colour. I have used a `ComboBox`.

How do get the program to see what selection the user has made in order to   display it in a `MessageBox`? I was thinking of using an `if` statement.

```
string red;
string blue;
string white;
string green;
string purple;
string yellow;
string colour = "";
```

Comment: In the title, you said ListBox, and then in the question, it's ComboBox. Which one are you using ?

Comment: what not use a color picker instead?

Comment: what GUI technology are you using? WPF, Winforms ect... ? Usually a control with selection has a `SelectedIndexChanged` event which will be fired, when the user chooses something. And the control will give you the value directly there is no need for any if statements.

Comment: please show us the code which populates the listbox or combobox.

Comment: Answers will be different for WPF and WinForms. Please add on which you are working on. WinForms example: [SelectedIndexChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.8), in WPF you'd rather work with binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SelectedIndexChanged event handler.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Might be worth adding that this refers to WinForms.